# Sync Data from ElasticSearch to MySQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, etl

i'm using elasticsearch to record a lot of messages. I want to create a ETL process with this ES data and create a DW in MySQL. 
What is the best tool to get data from ES, create a ETL process and insert it into MySQL DB?

Comment: May you please defibe what is ETL and DW?

Comment: ^ Extract, Transform, Load and Data Warehouse.  OP: what you're describing is a common practice in Elasticsearch for logging.  Consider looking at "Cold Indices"  and "Retiring Data".